# Сделать PhotoView для всеx фото

Tags: android, photoview

```
private final String[] imageNames={"img1", "img2", "img3","img4", "img5", "img6"};
private int currentIndex;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    PhotoView photoView = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.photo_view);
    photoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
}
```

Как прописать в  `photoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);`все шесть фото?

```
`private void previousImage()  {
    if(currentIndex > 0) {
        currentIndex--;
    }else  {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Previous Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    this.showImage(currentIndex);
}
private void nextImage()  {
    if(currentIndex < this.imageNames.length-1) {
        currentIndex++;
    }else  {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Next Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    this.showImage(currentIndex);` код работы кнопок
```

Comment: И как это должно в результате выглядеть визуально?

Comment: PhotoView должен работать со всеми снимками , а не с "img1".

Comment: @Магатрон3000, т.е. надо их листать влево-вправо? Или какой-то кнопкой переключать на следующий? Так-то один `PhotoView` может за раз только одну картинку отобразить.

Comment: есть кнопки "Следующая" и "Предыдущая", они листают картинки. Но с PhotoView, они не работают, стоит только одна (первая) картинка и все. Как можно применить для всего содержимого?

Comment: Покажите код с этими кнопками и как они листают картинки без PhotoView.